# I couldn't figure out the table markup for this table

Tags: html, html-table

[image]

I have tried to layout this table using rowspan and colspan for the last 2 hours and I couldn't figure it out, I would like to see if someone can solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let check this solution:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td rowspan=2>1.3</td>
    <td rowspan=4>1.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>2.1</td>
    <!--<td>2.2</td>-->
    <!--<td>2.3</td>-->
    <!--<td>2.4</td>-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--<td>3.1</td>-->
    <!--<td>3.2</td>-->
    <td rowspan=2>3.3</td>
    <!--<td>3.4</td>-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >4.1</td>
    <!--<td>4.2</td>-->
    <!--<td>4.3</td>-->
    <!--<td>4.4</td>-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;//It only work for fixed height. Haven't found better solution yet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pen where you can see a working solution:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XamVLo)

I added some color to make it visible.
To help you to construct table, here is how I did it:

- First, you have 4 rows.
- In the first one, you will have 4 cells, because they all start at the top.
- One cell starts in the second row, so, you add one cell in the second row.
- One cell starts in the third row, so you add one cell in the third row.
- One cell starts in the last row, so you add one cell in the last row.
- Then, you just need to add the `rowspan=""` accordingly to you scheme.

```css
    table {
  width:100%;
  height: 400px;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){
  background: #cceeee;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
  background: #eeccee;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1){
  background: #eecccc;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3){
  background: #ccccee;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1){
  background: #eeccee;
}
tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1){
  background: #eeccee;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4){
  background: #cceecc;
}
tr{
  height:25%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```